# How to use propely Sweet Alert with Redirect in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, sweetalert

After I update my data, Sweet Alert is not working when redirecting to my view page. Here is the code:

```
if ($request -> isMethod('POST')) {
        $action = Actionnaire::findOrFail($id);
        $action -> update($request->all());

        Alert::success('Success Message', 'Modifié avec succès');

    return redirect('/view-act/'.$id)->with('success');
    }
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors in your log?

Comment: No I d'ont get any error